# java.sql.SQLException: createStatement() is called on closed connection

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, apache-karaf, aries

In my project I wish to have api end point to get order detail.Internally it use ORM and database connection pooling. The process works but some time once in ten days I get following error message and api processing failed.Any idea what could be the problem and possible solution?

Tool used

Apache Karaf (4.1.2)

Apache cxf for api

hibernate 5.2.10

Additional bundles

```
167 │ Active   │  80 │ 2.1.0               │ Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
168 │ Active   │  80 │ 1.3.3               │ Apache Aries Transaction Manager
244 │ Active   │  80 │ 1.1.0               │ OPS4J Pax JDBC Pooling Aries Transaction JDBC
```

Connection pooling ([OPS4J Pax Jdbc](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJDBC/pages/61767710/Create+DataSource+from+config))

```
osgi.jdbc.driver.name=mariadb
dataSourceName=Order
databaseName=order_database
user=user1
password=user1
pool=aries
xa=true
url=jdbc:mysql://ip/mydb?characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPools=true
```

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="myorder" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=myorder)</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Error log stack trace

```
     | ERROR | qtp1522571225-12593 | OrderServiceRest                 | 126 - com.mycompany.olm.Order-application - 1.0.0.0 | Get Order Api failed for orderNo=1101
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147) [230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) [230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423) [230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463) [230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:107) [230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at com.mycompany.olm.order.repository.GenericRepository.findUniqueExistingEntityByPropertyValueEquality(GenericRepository.java:109) [130:com.mycompany.olm.Order-infrastructure:1.0.0.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor378.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54) [36:org.apache.aries.proxy:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119) [36:org.apache.aries.proxy:1.1.1]
    at com.mycompany.olm.order.repository.$OrderRepo1496888859.findUniqueExistingEntityByPropertyValueEquality(Unknown Source) [130:com.mycompany.olm.Order-infrastructure:1.0.0.0]
    at com.mycompany.olm.persistence.OrderPersistenceServiceImpl.findByOrderNumber(OrderPersistenceServiceImpl.java:23) [130:com.mycompany.olm.Order-infrastructure:1.0.0.0]
    at Proxy4e2856b2_5257_441c_8dcd_b768d177afda.findByOrderNumber(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.mycompany.olm.order.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.findByOrderNumber(OrderServiceImpl.java:27) [131:com.mycompany.olm.Order-service:1.0.0.0]
    at Proxy3f8ccbf8_c3f9_4d67_9aac_c3e79875e323.findByOrderNumber(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at Proxyf1210a3a_710e_42c7_af23_7e762904107c.findByOrderNumber(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.mycompany.olm.order.application.boundary.OrderServiceRest.getOrder(OrderServiceRest.java:61) [126:com.mycompany.olm.Order-application:1.0.0.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor377.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) [51:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [51:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189) [52:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) [52:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [51:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [51:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [51:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [51:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [30:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274) [59:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845) [92:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:584) [92:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71) [115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:6.0.6]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [89:org.eclipse.jetty.security:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:284) [115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:6.0.6]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512) [92:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80) [115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:6.0.6]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [84:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [84:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [84:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [94:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [94:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [94:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [94:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [94:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:?]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1940) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:379) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1488) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: createStatement() is called on closed connection
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.checkConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:240) ~[239:org.mariadb.jdbc:1.5.9.0]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.internalPrepareStatement(MariaDbConnection.java:430) ~[239:org.mariadb.jdbc:1.5.9.0]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.prepareStatement(MariaDbConnection.java:271) ~[239:org.mariadb.jdbc:1.5.9.0]
    at org.tranql.connector.jdbc.ConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(ConnectionHandle.java:241) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1940) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:379) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1488) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[230:org.hibernate.core:5.2.10.Final]
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: Maybe a threading issue: https://coderanch.com/t/306553/databases/java-sql-SQLException-Closed-Statement

Answer (score 0):

> The process works but some time once in ten days I get following error message and api processing failed.Any idea what could be the problem and possible solution?

Many database connections have a maximum lifetime. Once they have been open for that long they are automatically closed. MariaDB (the one that you reference) also closes connections that have been idle for a period of time. If your pool has not been configured to evict connections that are too old, or to evict idle connections more often than the back-end would close them, then you can end up in the situation where dead connections are in the pool. These would normally get picked up if your pool tests the connections before returning them, but you may not have a test query registered either.

In summary, you can probably configure around this by setting a maximum connection lifetime on the pool and/or an idle timeout.

These details are actually covered in the latest OSGi R7 standard called [Transaction Control](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.transaction.control.html). This provides a robust, managed lifecycle for resources (including JPA) with a more reliable integration model for modular Transaction Management. You may wish to look at this, or simply at the documentation for your pooling provider.